# Can anyone help me understand Lagrange Multipliers?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I'm currently trying to understand the method of Lagrange Multipliers. The explanation I'm currently looking at says something along the lines of

"Suppose we wish to minimise the function $f(x,y)$ subject to the constraint $g(x,y)=0$, and that this minimum is the point $(x_{0}, y_{0})$. Then $\nabla f(x_{0}, y_{0})$ is the normal to the function $f$ at this point. Furthermore, the normal vectors of $f$ and $g$ are are parallel.
Thus, $\nabla f(x_{0}, y_{0})=\lambda \nabla g(x_{0}, y_{0})$."

(Source: http://www.slimy.com/~steuard/teaching/tutorials/Lagrange.html)

I really don't understand why the normal vectors of $f$ and $g$ are are parallel, or how this gives rise to the equation $\nabla f(x_{0}, y_{0})=\lambda \nabla g(x_{0}, y_{0})$.

Could someone please explain this to me?

Many thanks.

Comment: The condition is $\nabla f=\lambda\nabla g$, not $\lambda\nabla f$. I hope that’s just a typo. If not, that might explain why you’re having trouble understanding this.

Answer (score 7):

$\vec \nabla f$ is not normal to the function $f$ , it is normal to a curve of constant $f$ -

more precisely $\vec \nabla f(x_0, y_0)$ is perpendicular to the tangent line to the curve defined by $f(x_0, y_0)=\text{Const.}$ at the point $(x_0, y_0)$

Lagrange multipliers deals with the situation in which you want to find the extrema of a function $f$ constrained to a curve of constant $g$

When you are constraint to a curve of constant $g$ you must always move in the direction of the tangent to the curve $g=$Const. - which is perpendicular to $\vec \nabla g$

To have a constrained extrema it must be true that the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction of the tangent plane to the constraining surface must vanish. This means that $\vec \nabla f$ must also be perpendicular to the curve $g=$Const.

Since both  $\vec \nabla f$  and  $\vec \nabla g$ are perpendicular to the same line, they must be parallel to each other

So    $\vec \nabla f = \lambda  \vec \nabla g$

Comment: Careful: in general $\nabla f$ and $\nabla g$ are both perpendicular to the same $(n-1)$-dimensional surface, and so they are parallel. In 3D or higher you can easily have two non-parallel vectors both perpendicular to the same curve. (I understand the OP uses two-dimensional language, but dealing with generalization is easier if you learn the general statement early.)

Comment: I started composing my answer in 3D  but changed my language when I noticed that the question was posed in 2D . The extension is not difficult , two vectors perpendicular to the same (n-1) dimensional tangent surface are necessary parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve always thought of it in terms of differentials and tangent vectors instead of gradients. If $f(\mathbf P)$ has an extremum at the point $\mathbf P_0$ then $\mathrm df_{\mathbf P_0}(\mathbf v)=0$ for any vector $\mathbf v$ that’s tangent to the curve $g(\mathbf P)=\text{constant}$. This is a level curve of $g$, so $\mathbf v$ also satisfies $\mathrm dg(\mathbf v)=0$. That means that at $\mathbf P_0$, $\mathrm df_{\mathbf P_0}$ must be a multiple of $\mathrm dg_{\mathbf P_0}$, say $\mathrm df=\lambda\mathrm dg$.

This translates pretty directly to gradients, which are orthogonal to tangents. The gradient of a function is always normal to its level curves, so $\nabla g$ is everywhere normal to the constraint curve $g(x,y)=0$. Now, the gradient of $f$ at a point gives the direction of fastest increase. The amount of change in other directions is $\nabla f\cdot\mathbf u$, where $\mathbf u$ is a unit vector that specifies the direction. That dot product is $0$ when $\mathbf u$ is orthogonal to $\nabla f$. So, for $f$’s value along some curve to be stationary (i.e., have a local extremum) at some point, $\nabla f$ must be normal to the curve there, i.e., parallel to $\nabla g$. This means that it must be some scalar multiple of $g$’s gradient, i.e., $\nabla f=\lambda\nabla g$.